# How a compiler make the defference between prefix and postix operators?

Tags: c++, c

We know ++ and - -  can be prefix or postfix and it depends on the position of the operand. for example :

`++a`  prefix because the operand is on the right of the operator.

`a++`  postfix because the operand is on the left of the operator.

But In complicated expressions things become confusing. for example :

`! - -a == ++ ! b`  I know to solve this i must apply the precedence rule but that depend on how i will consider the type of  ++ , a postfix or prefix.
My question how can i decide if an operator a postfix or a prefix and more generaly how can i determine the operand of an unary operator ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Use parenthesys if you're confused, ore take at look at  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: "_how can i decide if an operator a postfix or a prefix_" Look at whether it's _pre_ or _post_ the operand...?

Comment: @Scheff Then the program is bad and you should feel bad ;)

Comment: Read  the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools) then study the source code of existing C++ open source compilers such as [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). You could be interested in [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/)

Comment: As far as i know, if you have only two consecutives `+` or `-`, there is no possible confusion. For example `a++b` would not compile, neither `a ++b` nor `a++ b`. You need a space as in `a+ +b` but then it is not a prefix nor a postfix operator but a binary `+` followed bu an unary `+`. If you have `a+++b`, then it would means `a++ + b`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't.

Making some assumptions about type, your code should be:

```
!(-(-a)) == ++(!b)
```

Note the use of parentheses to obviate the need to even think about precedence.

Except this isn't a valid expression, because you can't increment an rvalue/temporary (assuming you aren't overloading `operator!` and returning a reference, which would be non-idiomatic and weird).

Also each side of the `==` should be split off into a variable declaration for clarity.

```
const bool isItHot = !a;
const bool isItCold = !b;  // ignoring your ++ for now

return (isItHot == isItCold);
```

If you really need a tool to work out the precedence for you, [Geordi can do it](http://www.eelis.net/geordi/#flags), or you can work it out from [some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: In the question it is `- -a` and not `--a`

Comment: @t.niese Good spot. Now, what is `! - -a` supposed to mean?

Comment: If it is really `! - -a` then it is `!(-(-a))`, so it could - depending on the type of `a` - just be `!a`.

Comment: `-(-a)`should always be equivalent to `a`. And the parenthesis in `++(!b)` is really superfluous. Too much parenthesis does not help readability.

Comment: @Phil1970 It does here. The fact that the OP didn't understand `++!b` tells us that.

Comment: @Phil1970 `-(-a)` is not necessarily equivalent to `a`, if the type of `a` is a custom class then the unary operator could have been overwritten. The question does not say anything about what type of  `a` is.